# How can I use ternary expression in react to render multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have three buttons assigned to a constant variable, and a input tag, now the goal is to write a tenary expression, such that, after the first button is clicked if the number entered in the input is greater than 18, it will change to the the second button, if it is less it will change to the third button

{this.state.userAge < 18 ? (this.state.userAge >= 18 ? buttonTwo : buttonOne): buttonThree}

I thought this will do the job, but it doesn't seems to be working, it only works when the number is greater than or equal to 18 and it outputs the third button, instead of the second

Comment: The second condition will never be true when the first condition is true -- think about it. BTW, it's ternary, not tenary.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `json`? There is no JSON here (removed tag).

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

It is due to order of your conditions in the ternary operator. You’re checking if `this.state.userAge` is less than 18 first, and if it’s not, you’re directly rendering buttonThree. It means that for any age 18 or above, it will always render buttonThree.

## Solution

```
{this.state.userAge > 18 ? buttonTwo : (this.state.userAge < 18 ? buttonOne : buttonThree)}
```